# Spring Boot Can't find main class Multi module

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle, groovy

I am having difficulties telling Spring the location of the Main class. So far I have only managed to correctly specify where it is when it is in pictures-service module (i.e., pictures-service/src/main/com.bachadiff.application/Application.java)

This is the file structure.

[image: This is the file structure.]

And this is the main gradle file.

```
       buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.2.RELEASE")
        }
    }

  plugins {
      id 'java'
      id 'java-library'
      id 'idea'
      id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.0.2.RELEASE"
      id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.5.RELEASE"
  }

    bootJar {
        baseName = 'com.bachadiff.pictures-service'
        version = '0.1.0'
        mainClassName = 'com.bachadiff.application.Application'

    }
    version = '0.1.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    ext.common = [
            spring_web  : 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.2.RELEASE',
            spring_rest : 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:2.0.2.RELEASE',
            spring_mongo: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.0.2.RELEASE',
            spring_test : 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    ]

    ext.test = [
            junit: 'junit:junit:4.12'
    ]

    dependencies {
        api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.2.RELEASE'
        api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:2.0.2.RELEASE'
        api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.0.2.RELEASE'
        compile project(':pictures-service-impl')
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    }
```

Comment: I am not familiar with spring at all, but have you tried using `mainClassName = 'com.bachadiff.application.Application'` instead? you can get the string you need to use by right clicking the selected class and then selecting "Copy Reference"

Comment: I can get the string, and it is exactly as you stated but when I put it in the main build.gradle it still can't find it. ( mainClassName = com.bachadiff.application.Application, or mainClassName = pictures-service-applications.com.bachadiff.application.Application)

Answer (score 0):

The `mainClassName` should consist out of the package and the class name itself, so in your case that should be:

```
mainClassName = 'com.bachadiff.application.Application'
```

And since you are saying that you have a multi-project build, you should put this in the `build.gradle` for the `pictures-service-application` project

Comment: When I said multi module I meant the Intellij modules. (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html). When I put the mainClassName in the application module gradlew build fails with manifest attribute must not be null

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot 1 or 2?

Comment: I am using Spring boot 2

Comment: Can you try to configure it using the `springBoot` task:

    springBoot {
        mainClassName = 'com.bachadiff.application.Application'
    }

Comment: I get a compile error saying that it can't find the mainClassName is an unknown property.

Comment: But did you add the Spring Boot Gradle plugin? According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/ it should work that way

Comment: I have updated the details in the answer. As far as I am aware I am doing it correctly.

Comment: Could you try to complete remove `bootJar` section because according to the documentation, Spring should find the main class automatically on the classpath (looking for a class with a public static void main)